# Laravel right server configuration for host several site

Tags: apache, laravel, file-permissions, vps

I got a Laravel project uploaded on a vps, I can't understand how to configure all things to have:

- more than one site(Laravel project) on the vps; (that is is tricky, because all configuration examples that I've found talking about pointing the root of the server to the public Laravel's folder)
- having .env and .composer and all the system folders not accessible directly;
- which are the right user and permission to set on the various folders;

In my system I've:

1. www-data classic apache group with standard privileges;
2. a non root user, used even to access to MySQL and ftp service;
3. a root user;

I'm using apache2 over Ubuntu server 16.04.

Comment: you can create multiple virtual hosts and define different paths for each laravel folder make sure you have access to change apache configuration. 

https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/serve-multiple-domains-by-using-virtual-hosts/

Comment: @Rodrane i can't simpli put varius folder with the right privileges with an .htacces for each public folder? is an test enviroment not for real user or accesible in some ways from user

Answer (score 0):

According to the Question, I assume that you want to host multiple Laravel Sites on the VPS without messing anything up!
Here we go!
Let's Assume that you create the Directories of your site in `/var/www` directory because it's where your Basic Apache directory will be.
**Configuration for *Site 1***:
*->Virtual Host for Site 1*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "var/www/site1/public"
    ServerName www.site1.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

*-> Directory for Site 1 (Upload your Project here)*: `/var/www/site1`

**Configuration for Site 2:**
*->Virtual Host for Site 2*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "var/www/site2/public"
    ServerName www.site2.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

*-> Directory for Site 2 (Upload your Project here)*: `/var/www/site2`
**Here is the Trick!** As Laravel have its `index.php` file in the **Public** Folder of the Project, Your Domains will point to `/var/www/site-x/public` folder for the specific site! They will have their own `composer` and `config` files in `/var/www/site-x/` directories of their own!
 So, This is how you can host multiple Laravel sites on the same VPS without messing anything up! I am using the same technique! I think it's the only one trick to do so! Let me know if that works!

Comment: that's will work even with no dns and pointing both on the same port? i've no www.site2 or whatever... just a plain ip address

Comment: You have to point your domain to IP of your Server (A record). Other than that, Apache will handle with the trick given in answer!

Comment: so isnt possible without a dns